# angular 6 application deployment on tomcat

Tags: angular, tomcat

I have an Angular 6 application.I have to serve it through tomcat server.
Steps I did: I build it through ng-build and put the dist folder in tomcat/webapps folder.It is giving me the login page on 7070 port which is my tomcat port.
But I have Auth application running on 8080 port seperately(not on tomcat) and also my Api's are running on different port in tomcat.So how will I communicate with this application and my Apis. 
Currently, my auth api is giving 404.

Comment: In local machine I did proxy configuration for this API and Auth application like this: "/auth/*":{
        "target":"http://localhost:8080",
        "secure":true,
        "changeOrigin":true,
        "logLevel": "debug"  
    },
    "/Query_api/*":{
        "target":"http://localhost:7070",
        "secure":true,
        "changeOrigin":true,
        "logLevel": "debug"  
    }

Comment: Tell us what happens if you are hitting any api http://localhost:8080/auth/ from browser ?

Comment: It is giving me auth application page when i am using seperately